# Atualiza Preço ao selecionar atributo [Magento]

Tags: php, magento

Quando seleciono uma opção no atributo, por exemplo:

```
P
M
G
GG = 25.00
```

o preço não atualiza, como faço para atualizar assim que selecionar a opção...

minha versão do magento é ==== 1.9.3.1 ====

Comment: Você criou um `bundle product`? Configurou corretamente os valores? Verificou se está ocorrendo algum erro no javascript através do console do navegador?

Comment: Sim aparece o seguinte erro. 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'changePrice' of undefined